# assert(false) does not stop execution

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, assert

In one of my JUnit test, I'm initializing an object:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(220, 120, 0.05, true);
```

The constructor's signature is:

```
public MyObject(int minLength, int maxLength, 
                double onBitsRatio, boolean forceAtLeastOneBitOn)
```

Followed by:

```
assert(onBitsRatio >= 0.0 && onBitsRatio <= 1.0);
assert(maxLength>=minLength);
assert(false);
```

Oddly enough, the assertions don't stop the execution, as I expect them to.

Why is JUnit ignoring these assertions?

Comment: PS, it looks like you are checking arguments. That's not what asserts are for. This would be correct if you're asserting that no state of the program, regardless of external input, fails these conditions. Usually asserts concerning private stuff.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

JUnit is not ignoring these assertions, because as you say, you are using Java's `assert` keyword. This is handled by the JVM, not JUnit.

The answer is almost certainly that your JVM assertions are turned off. In fact they are off unless you turn them on with `-ea`. These are ignored otherwise.

Comment: can't explain why so many upvotes in the other answer that is wrong/incomplete ... democracy does not always work in SO. I upvoted yours because it is straight to the point without making any confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you are using proper assert from JUnit?

If you are using normal java assert, these are turned off by default. You have to enable them explicitly.

Try to use this: `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(false)`
As far as I know, there is no method in the JUnit Assert library that is called just `assert()`

Seeing as your asserts are in some object, and you want the test to fail, then you need to enable the assert. 
Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) describing how you can enable assertions.

Comment: I'm not using JUnit's Assert, just the ordinary java assert.

Comment: And `Assert.assertTrue(false);` actually stops the execution and fails the test with `java.lang.AssertionError`.

Comment: You are not supposed to use java asserts in JUnit tests. You are supposed to use JUnit asserts. If you want to enable java asserts you have to do with with the -ea jvm option.

Comment: I don't think the `assert` is part of the test. It's part of an object being tested, and it's asserting about its internal state.

Comment: @SeanOwen - exactly, these `assert()`s belong to the class being tested, not to the JUnit test.

Comment: @AdamMatan Then you need to explicitly enable the assertions. Look at my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Change them to JUnit assertions, you are using plain [Java assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html), that are disabled by default in the jvm:

```
assertTrue(onBitsRatio >= 0.0 && onBitsRatio <= 1.0);
assertTrue(maxLength>=minLength);
assertTrue(false);
```

If you really want to use java assertions, make sure you have `-enableassertions` as a parameter in your run configuration.

As per your question tags you are using eclipse, so go to run as -> run configurations and add `-enableassertions` or `-ea` in the VM arguments tab.

Answer (score 1):

From *Java The Complete Reference*:

"
To enable assertion checking at run time, you must specify the -ea option. For example, to enable assertions for AssertDemo, execute it using this line:

`java -ea AssertDemo`
"